# Combine output files from Proc GLM in SAS

Tags: sas, glm, proc

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible, so I thought I would check with more experienced SAS users.

I want to run Proc GLM many, many times using the "by" statement and then have output parameters for each run go into a single a file. The output parameters are something like a, b, # points, and R2.

Is this possible?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output the results from `proc glm` in a (several) table(s).

To retrieve the output of `proc glm`, one can use the `ods trace statement` to track the object(s) output of `proc glm`. For more information, please consider reading the [ODS TRACE Statement](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=odsug&docsetTarget=p1fpt3uuow90o3n155hs7bp1mo7f.htm&locale=en) documentation.

`proc glm` output 6 objects: `NObs`, `OverallANOVA`, `FitStatistics`, `ModelANOVA`, `ModelANOVA` and `ParameterEstimates`.

```
29         ods trace on;
30         proc glm data=sashelp.cars;
31          model length = mpg_city ;
32         quit;


Output Added:
-------------
Name:       NObs
Label:      Number of Observations
Template:   STAT.GLM.NObsNotitle
Path:       GLM.Data.NObs
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       OverallANOVA
Label:      Overall ANOVA
Template:   stat.GLM.OverallANOVA
Path:       GLM.ANOVA.Length.OverallANOVA
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       FitStatistics
Label:      Fit Statistics
Template:   stat.GLM.FitStatistics
Path:       GLM.ANOVA.Length.FitStatistics
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       ModelANOVA
Label:      Type I Model ANOVA
Template:   stat.GLM.Tests
Path:       GLM.ANOVA.Length.ModelANOVA
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       ModelANOVA
Label:      Type III Model ANOVA
Template:   stat.GLM.Tests
Path:       GLM.ANOVA.Length.ModelANOVA
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       ParameterEstimates
Label:      Solution
Template:   stat.GLM.Estimates
Path:       GLM.ANOVA.Length.ParameterEstimates
-------------
```

I induce that by `a,b and # points` you are pointing to the `estimate` parameter that can be found in the `ParameterEstimates` object. The coefficient of determination however can be found in the `FitStatistics` object.

Let's say you want to run many `proc glm` and append the results in a single table (actually two, considering that you will end up with one table for the estimates and one for the coefficients of determination). You can create a macro that will take the result of each `proc glm` and append it to a table.

```
%macro glm(y, x);
ods output ParameterEstimates=temp_parameters FitStatistics=temp_fit;

proc glm data=sashelp.cars;
    model &y. = &x. ;
quit;


proc append data=temp_parameters base=parameters;run;
proc append data=temp_fit base=fit;run;

proc datasets lib=work nolist nodetails; delete temp_:;run;
%mend;

%glm(length, mpg_city);
%glm(length, cylinders);
%glm(length, weight);
```

The two final tables are created, one populated with the estimates (`parameters` table) and one populated with the coefficient of determination (`fit` table).

`parameters` table:

[image]

`fit` table:

[image]

Unfortunately, without more information about your problem and no data, I can't assist further.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will give it a try and if I can't get it to work I will edit my question to include a subset of data for example